# Coldfusion-9 Trim Values

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to write a code that takes a URL that has 3 parts (www).(domainname).(com) and trim the first part out completely.

So far I have this code that checks if on the left side I don't have a 'www' or 'dev'
go in and set `siteDomainName = removecharsCGI.SERVER_NAME,1,2);`

```
if (numHostParts eq 3 and listfindnocase('www,dev',left(CGI.SERVER_NAME,3)) eq 0) {
        siteDomainName = removecharsCGI.SERVER_NAME,1,2);
```

The problem with the code above is that is deleting only 2 characters where I need it to delete ALL characters until `numHostParts eq 2` or at least until the first "."

Another example would be:

akjnakdn.example.com   I need the code to delete the first part of the URL with the dot included (akjnakdn.)

This code will help some of the queries that i have on the site to stop crushing because they are related with the #URL# and when the #URL# is fake I am getting `cform query returned zero records` error that is causing my contact forms to stop working.

Comment: Are you trying to do a canonical domain name?

Comment: As an aside, a query returning zero records is an expected condition that should be handled. Normally it should not cause an error.

Comment: Well, it does not return an error to the user, it returns a message saying that the form does not work but the rest of the site is working as it should.

Comment: Well I know nothing about your application. I am just going off of your earlier comment "error that is causing my contact forms to stop working". It sounds you need more user friendly error handling, like "sorry, the xyz value you entered is not valid" rather than saying "the form doesn't work".

Comment: .. and probably validate the values earlier in the process as well.

Comment: The form does not stop working because of an invalid input but rather an invalid URL. The way the site is setup is way too complicated to explain how it works here. My question was "how do i trim the left part of something using '.' as a delimiter" I apologize if the way I asked the question confused you.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I remember your last few questions ultimately turned out to be a little more involved than initially described.. and the  comments suggested this might be as well. But sounds like this one is straight-forward :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<cfscript> 
    local.nameArr = ListToArray(CGI.SERVER_NAME, '.');
    if (ArrayLen(local.nameArr) gt 2) {
        ArrayDeleteAt(local.nameArr, 1);
    }
    siteDomainName = ArrayToList(local.nameArr, '.');
</cfscript>
```

I've split the server name into array elements with a period as the delimiter.  If the number of elements is greater than two, remove the first element.  Then convert it back to a list with the period as a delimiter.

UPDATE

As suggested by Robb, this could be more concise and perform better by skipping the array conversion process:

```
<cfscript> 
    siteDomainName = CGI.SERVER_NAME;
    if (ListLen(siteDomainName, '.') gt 2) {
        siteDomainName = ListDeleteAt(siteDomainName, 1, '.');
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: I would approach it in the same way but instead of converting it to an array, just do a ListLen() and if its greater than 2, ListDeleteAt() using a . as the delimiter.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `listRest`.  It returns all the elements in a list, except the first one.  Documentation is here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d87.html

Example:

```
<cfscript>
name = cgi.server_name;
if (listlen(name,".") gte 3) {
  name = listRest(name,".");
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Well, there's a function I didn't know (or forgot) CF had!

Comment: It is a super useful function, along w/ listFirst() & listLast() for parsing lists, you can even use listFirst() & listRest() for Prolog style Head|Tail recursion.

Comment: Rats... I completely forgot about listRest() - I use last and first all the time... thanks for the reminder.

Comment: This is certainly the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression, since you only want to "trim" certain subdomains (`www`,`dev`).

```
<cfset the_domain = REReplaceNoCase(cgi.SERVER_NAME, "(www|dev)\.", "") />
```

Just use a `|`-delimited list of subdomains you want to trim within the parentheses.

Comment: I actually want to trim all of them except a specific subdomain that I need. For instance now my website works with what ever you put in front of the domain name

Comment: I do prefer this solution if there were only specific prefixes to strip.  However, the OP also listed `akjnakdn.example.com` as an example.

Comment: True, regex doesn't make it easy to code exclusions rather than inclusion.